# How to make Win7 guest in Parallels 5 use Mac media keyboard shortcuts

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, keyboard-shortcuts, parallels

I am using a Mac Pro as my host machine with Windows 7 64-bit running as a guest in Parallels 5. My issue is that I do not like iTunes and prefer running foobar2000 in Windows, however by doing this I lose usage of my media shortcut keys on my Mac keyboard. I've looked for different software or reg changes so that I can push the media keys to my Guest system but have failed to find any that recognize the function keys. Even Parallels built in key mapping options don't allow mapping the function keys. I need to be able to map `F7-F9` to Windows as media keys (`F10-F12` continue to work as the master volume is controlled by Mac...however if it's possible to map those as well I'd want to as Windows handles application specific volume controls while Mac fails to do so) In the Parallels Keyboard & Mouse settings there is the following option:

[image]

As you can see I have the option selected, however it doesn't seem to work in reverse.

As always any assistance is greatly appreciated, and if you need any further information please let me know.